# How to archive a on-premise sql server database to azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

We have an on-premise database of about eight terabytes that we are trying to archive to Azure. How can we go about it?

This archive needs to be accessible because we might need to pull data from it in the future.

I have read about azure data lake, blob storage and data factory but i still don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by archive. Do you want to keep a backup of the database available to restore? Do you want to export the schema and data and keep that saved? Do you need to recover at the object level or only the whole database?

Answer (score 0):

The best way for an archival would be to create a serverless database and copy the data from On Prem database to serverless database .
you can copy the data via :

1. Azure data factory
2. SSIS
3. creating a linked server and copying data between databases(this would be very slow)
4. data sync in Azure SQL database

In case if you dont want a physical database, you can take/create a bacpac and then preserver it in Azure blob staorage